# Magento problem on anchor categories with title SEO

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

I have a problem on my website

Magento doesn't take the right title. Instead of taking the title given in backoffice, it takes the default title. Only anchor categories are concerned.

Can you help me ?

Its 'okay

Category.xml called another block for non anchor categories

```
<block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.content" template="catalog/navigation/content.phtml"/>
```

This block allows to display all children categories and not products in content. 
But as it called navigation.php, metas title and description aren't managed.

Comment: Nothing. I'm trying to find which file in app/code/Mage/Catalog is controlling this (sorry for my english). Layout is ok, phtml is ok so it's coming from code. My another website has the same problem. Maybe a bug with a module ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error could be coming from multiple places. The easiest and first thing to check is whether you have reindexed your category flat data recently. This should happen automatically when you save, but things do happen.

As a troubleshooting measure, I would then try disabling using flat data for categories. You can find this setting in `System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > "Use Flat Catalog Category"`.

Next, I would disable all extensions (not in `System > Configuration`, but going into each file in `app/etc/modules/` that doesn't start with `Mage` and set the `active` node to be `false`). If that fixes the problem, re-enable each module one at a time to see which one breaks the category name.

The template that is outputting the name is: `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/category/view.phtml`.

The category is found in `app/code/Mage/Catalog/Model/Category.php`. However, I doubt that this will yield any results.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Hum Use flat catalog category isn't active so this isn't the problem. Ok i'm going to disable modules one per one.

Comment: Hum i disabled my modules and nothing change.. I really don't understand. On a blank magento 1.9.2 it's working and on my two websites it's not working. So there is a conflict or a bug somewhere but i don't know where..

Comment: Have you disabled all caches?

Comment: Yes in order to test but always the same problem...

Comment: ok I understand. My layout catalog.xml called a different file for a non anchor category in order to display only sub categories and no products.

Comment: That would make sense then. It will usually be something like that.